# Installing a package which is only available on a different version of Ubuntu

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, backport

I want to use the Python wrapper PyKDL for KDL, the Kinematics and Dynamics Library.  PyKDL is only packaged [beginning with 19.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pykdl).  I installed PyKDL using pip3 on my 18.04 system.  In an interactive Python environment I get the following error if I attempt `import PyDKL`: `ImportError: liborocos-kdl.so.1.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

I installed the liborcos-kdl-dev package but in [18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/liborocos-kdl-dev) but the needed version of the shared library is found in the version 1.4.0-7 of the package in [19.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/liborocos-kdl-dev).

How do I get the updated package from the later version of Ubuntu to meet the PyPi dependency while running the most recent Long-Term Support version?

Comment: What about using a virtual machine?

Comment: did you ever found a solution?